# JavaFX ToggleGroup in SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

In JavaFX exists the control [ToggleGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html). I have installed the `SceneBuilder`, version:

```
Product Version
JavaFX Scene Builder 8.0.0

Build Information
Version 8.0.0
Date: 2015-03-25
Java Version: 1.8.0_40-b25, Oracle Corporation
```

I can't find this control in the `SceneBuilder`:

[image: screenshot scenebuilder]

Can you help me?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 32):

You can set it in the properties.  It is not a visual control, but a grouping.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The ToggleGroup is not a control. When you have created a ToggleButton you can select it in SceneBuilder. Then you will find a field on the right side within the inspector named "Toggle Group". Add a name there and SceneBuilder will put the ToggleButton together with all other ToggleButtons which you give the same group name into a ToggleGroup. You can inject the toggle group into your controller in the usual way.